# 3D css - translate or rotate div with before and after pseudo content

Tags: css

Here is a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/xebuti/edit?html,css,output) of what I have so far.

I want to create a 3d hexagonal prism made up of 2 hexagons and some divs that will make up the body:

[image]

My hexagons are made up of the following markup:

```
<div class="hexagon-wrapper">
  <div class="hexagon"></div>
</div>
```

The css uses the pseudo `:before` and `:after` selectors to create additional content that rotated 60 degrees to make the shape of the hexagon:

```
.hexagon-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px; 
}

.hexagon {
  height: 100%;
  width: 57.735%;
  display: inline-block; 
}

.hexagon:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  content: '';
  transform: rotate(60deg);
  transform-origin: 25% 25%; 
}

.hexagon:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  content: '';
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
  transform-origin: 25% 75%; 
}
```

The problem is, when I try and translate one of the hexagons:

```
.hexagon-wrapper:first-child .hexagon {
  background-color: #D93;
  transform: translateZ(100px);
}
```

The hexagon gets distorted as you can see [here](http://jsbin.com/kunule/edit?html,css,output).

How can I translate or rotate the hexagon.

Comment: You may want to look at http://tridiv.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you apply `translateZ(X)` to the parent it messes up the `inherit` values for `width` in the child.

The solution is to use `width:100%` instead of `inherit` but then the one without `translateZ(X)` will mess up. So the solution is to use `translateZ(0)` on it.

### [Demo](http://jsbin.com/zekeziyore/edit?html,css,output)

```
.hexagon:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  width: 100%;
  content: '';
  transform: rotate(60deg);
  transform-origin: 25% 25%; 
}

.hexagon:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  width: 100%;
  content: '';
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
  transform-origin: 25% 75%; 
}

.hexagon-wrapper:first-child .hexagon {
  background-color: #D93;
  transform: translateZ(100px);
}


.hexagon-wrapper:nth-child(2) .hexagon {
  background-color: #6C6; 
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**3D Rotating Pentagon Code**

```css
#stage { 
  margin: 75px auto 0 auto;
  max-width: 253px;
  position: relative;
}
.spinner .face {    
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    width: 280px;
    height: 135px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 48px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 4px 0;
}

.spinner .face--first { 
    background: tomato;
    transform: rotateY( 0deg ) translateZ(100px);
}
.spinner .face--second { 
    background: orange;
    transform: rotateX(72deg) translateZ(100px); 
}
.spinner .face--third { 
    background: blue;
    transform: rotateX(144deg) translateZ(100px); 
}
.spinner .face--fourth { 
    /*background: lime;*/
    transform: rotateX(216deg) translateZ(100px); 
}
.spinner  .face--fifth {
    background: red;
    transform: rotateX(-72deg) translateZ(100px); 
}

.spinner {
 animation: spincube 8s infinite linear; 
  /*transform:rotateY(96deg);*/
  position: relative;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
   
}

@-webkit-keyframes spincube {
    from {
    transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
   }

   to {
    transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(360deg);
   }
}



#pentagon {
    width:380px;
    height:380px;
    z-index: 11111;
    overflow: hidden;
 
   
}
#pentagon .inner {
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transform:scaleY(1.05146) skewX(-19deg) rotate(36deg) translateY(-36.33%) rotate(18deg) skewY(54deg) scaleX(0.58779);
    transform: scaleY(1.05146) skewX(-19deg) rotate(36deg) translateY(-36.33%) rotate(18deg) skewY(54deg) scaleX(0.58779);
}

#pentagon .inner:before {
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    display: block;
    content: '';
    background:#333 url(surface_side_default.jpg) no-repeat right bottom;
     background-size: 78% 62%;
    background-position: 22px 158px;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1.7013) skewY(-54deg) rotate(-18deg) translateY(-12.67%);
    transform:scaleX(1.7013) skewY(-54deg) rotate(-18deg) translateY(-12.67%);
}
.transide1{
     position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform:rotateX(-18deg) rotateY(-90deg) skewX(19deg) scaleY(0.95106) translateX(-80px) translateY(-34px) translateZ(-92px);
    transform:rotateX(-18deg) rotateY(-90deg) skewX(19deg) scaleY(0.95106) translateX(-80px) translateY(-34px) translateZ(-92px);
}

.transide2{
  -webkit-transform:rotateX(-18deg) rotateY(-90deg) skewX(19deg) scaleY(0.95106) translateX(-80px) translateY(-34px) translateZ(190px);
    transform:rotateX(-18deg) rotateY(-90deg) skewX(19deg) scaleY(0.95106) translateX(-80px) translateY(-34px) translateZ(190px);
}
```

```html
<div id="stage">
    <div class="spinner">
     <div  id="pentagon" class=" transide1"><div class="inner"></div></div>
        <div class="face face--first"><img src="surface_side_default.jpg" height="140" width="280" /></div>
        <div class="face face--first"><img src="surface_side_default.jpg" height="140" width="280" /></div>
        <div class="face face--second"><img src="surface_side_default.jpg" height="140" width="280" /></div>
        <div class="face face--third"><img src="surface_side_default.jpg" height="140" width="280" /></div>
        <div class="face face--fourth"><img src="surface_side_default.jpg" height="140" width="280" /></div>
        <div class="face face--fifth"><img src="surface_side_default.jpg" height="140" width="280" /></div>
        <div  id="pentagon" class=" transide2"><div class="inner"></div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! PO is asking for an hexagon code and you bring a pentagon code? Even if useful (it does not to be) you should explain it.